# increasing correlation values - R

Tags: r, correlation, maximize

I would like to obtain the pairs of values that decrease the correlation between two vectors by using a threshold and to find the values that maximize the correlation, with the restriction to have at least three pairs of values.  I am using R.

For example, suppose to have this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(val1 = c(1,2,4,8,10,20), val2 = c(2,4,8,16, 35, 14)) 
rownames(df) <- c('a','b','c','d','e','f')
```

I would like remove the pairs of values that don't allow me to obtain a correlation greater than 0.6, so in this case I would like to find that f element (row) decreases my correlation. Lastly, if it is easy, I would like to find that by using a,b,c,d elements (rows) I can obtain the highest correlation.

Do you have any idea how I can do it?

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Best

Comment: You need more restrictions. If you remove all of the rows except 2 (any 2), the correlation is +1 or -1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help! I updated the text and added the restrictions to have at least 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

The restriction of at least 3 rows helps. There are two ways to approach the problem. Which one is best depends a bit on what you are trying to accomplish. We can start with all of the points and remove one at a time or we can start with 3 points and add one at a time. Your example has 6 points so it does not make that much difference. Here is code to find the best 3 point combination:

```
combos <- combn(6, 3)
corrs <- combn(6, 3, function(x) cor(df[x, ])[1, 2])
results <- cbind(t(combos), corrs)
head(results[order(corrs, decreasing=TRUE), ])
#                corrs
# [1,] 1 2 3 1.0000000
# [2,] 1 2 4 1.0000000
# [3,] 2 3 4 1.0000000
# [4,] 1 3 4 1.0000000
# [5,] 1 2 5 0.9988739
# [6,] 1 2 6 0.9940219
```

We use the `combn()` function twice, once to get a matrix of the possible combinations of 3 items out of 6 and a second time to apply the correlation function to each combination
Then we combine the results and list the best 6. There are three best 3-point solutions having correlations of +1. For the 5-point solutions we get the following:

```
combos <- combn(6, 5)
corrs <- combn(6, 5, function(x) cor(df[x, ])[1, 2])
results <- cbind(t(combos), corrs)
head(results[order(corrs, decreasing=TRUE), ])
#                    corrs
# [1,] 1 2 3 4 5 0.9381942
# [2,] 1 2 3 4 6 0.7514174
# [3,] 1 2 3 5 6 0.4908234
# [4,] 1 2 4 5 6 0.4639890
# [5,] 1 3 4 5 6 0.4062324
# [6,] 2 3 4 5 6 0.3591037
```

Now there is one clear solution which excludes point 6 ("f") with a correlation of +.938. In general the size of the correlation will increase with decreasing points until it reaches +1 or -1. As the number of points increases, it will take more processing time to compute all of the alternatives. A short cut would be to look at deviations from the first principal component:

```
df.pca <- prcomp(df)
abval <- abs(df.pca$x[, "PC2"])
df.pca$x[order(abval, decreasing=TRUE), "PC2"]
#           f           e           a           b           c           d 
# -11.4055987   5.3497271   2.1507072   1.9191656   1.4560825   0.5299163
```

Point f (the 6th point) has the largest deviation from the first principal component so removing it should improve the correlation. Likewise removing e and f gives the best 4-point correlation. This is simpler, but generally you would want to remove a point, compute the principal components with that point removed and then identify the next point for removal.

Comment: thank you for your help! I have just a question.. why do you look to the PC2 and not to PC1? Thank you in advance!

Comment: PC1 is the major axis of the correlation between val1 and val2. Deviations away from that line (and therefore reducing the correlation) are PC2. If the correlation was +1 or -1, all of the points would be on the line defined by PC1.